# In nestjs with passportjs and graphql api, how should I create the auth module for two different types of users that have different schema?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, passport.js

I'm trying to write the auth module in nestjs for two different users, assuming they're called user1 and user2. These users have distinct graphql schema and different business logic. How should I write my auth module to perform functions like login and validate user and granting jwt tokens using passportjs?

I can think of two different methods.

The first method is to create a parent user class for user1 and user2 and have these two classes inherit from the parent class. Then in my auth module I only have to operate the auth related function calls on the parent user class and not the child class.

Another approach is to define a user class that can link to specific type of user objects, perhaps inside an array. So my auth module performs auth operations on the user class and the user class is what's returned to the person requesting to log in. To access the specific user data, the requester simply needs to follow the link to the specific user object in the generic user.

Can someone comments on these methods or provide the actual way I should implement this?

Thanks!

I am still doing research on authentication with passportjs.